# Как исправить эту ошибку в django?

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста,
В чем тут ошибка , и как её исправить?

Comment: Для начала перенесите тексты из картинки в текст вопроса. Картинку удалите. Потом почитайте про обработку исключений в Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
except ImportError, e:
```

на

```
except ImportError as e:
```